# Wait for previous process to finish before starting new one

Tags: subprocess, autohotkey

I need to find a way in AHK to wait for a program to finish, before starting a new one.

Basically, I have a script that opens an application and inputs some parameters. The application then spends an unknown amount of time processing the input data.

Unfortunately, at the moment the ahk script ends before the application has finished processing, at which point the same ahk script is run again and does not work / interrupts the previous processing.

**edit:** (the ahk .exe is called using subprocess calls in Python)

is there a way or any methods to help with this?

For reference, the script:

```
#NoEnv
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendInput Mode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#WinActivateForce
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1

if 0 < 2  ; The left side of a non-expression if-statement is always the name     of a variable.
{
    MsgBox, This script requires 2 incoming parameters but it only received     %0%.
    ExitApp
}
IfWinNotExist, ahk_exe photoscan.exe
{
    Run, "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\photoscan.exe"
}
sleep, 200
WinActivate, ahk_exe photoscan.exe
sleep,5
WinMaximize, ahk_exe photoscan.exe
;Macro5:
Click, 476, 438, 0
SendInput {LControl Down}
SendInput {r}
Click, -56, 157, 0
WinActivate, Run Python Script ahk_class QWidget
sleep, 400
SendInput {LControl Up}
SendInput {LControl Down}
SendInput {a}
SendInput {LControl Up}
sleep, 400
SendInput {Backspace}
SendInput %1% ; 1st argument is the photoScan API scriptimages folder     directory
SendInput {Tab}
SendInput {Tab}
sleep, 400
SendInput {LControl Down}
SendInput {a} ; 2nd argument is additional args (in our case, the     projectName)
SendInput {LControl Up}
SendInput {Backspace}
SendInput %2% ; 2nd argument is the images folder directory & name of output log, model and texture
Sleep, 703
SendInput {Enter}
Click, 476, 438, 0
Return
```

Comment: What language is this? It's certainly not Python.

Comment: AutoHotKey (AHK). But it's being called by the subprocess module within Python. I linked Python because I didn't know if there was something in Python I could use as well as AHK

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
IfWinNotExist, ahk_exe photoscan.exe
{
    Run, "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\photoscan.exe"
}
sleep, 200
```

Which is set to start/launch the application if it is not running.  Then a sleep to allow two tenths of a second for it to load (which is probably too small).

Instead of just a ‘sleep’ you have to ‘WinWait’ or ‘WinWaitActive’, found at this link:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm

Like this sample:

```
Run, "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\photoscan.exe"
WinWaitActive, ahk_exe photoscan.exe, , 2
if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, WinWait timed out.
    return
}
else
    WinMinimize  ; minimize the window found by WinWaitActive.
```

You may also have to use the window inspector to get the true name of the window/application/process name.